# After vue-cli uploads the server, the request server image path is more /dist/

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

**scenes:**

The demo loads all resources normally, Image can be uploaded correctly，But request an extra `/dist/` for image paths. image 404

**Demo on the server**

[image]

The demo configuration:

```
vue.config.js:

module.exports = {

  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/dist/" : "/",
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/demo": {
        target: "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }

  }
};
```

```
router.js

export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: "/dist/",
  routes: [...]
})
```

I'm going to put the `dist` folder in the server directory

I want to get rid of /dist/ field and let image load correctly

`Vue-CLi` automatically splicing image paths, local testing is fine, but deployment server is much more `/dist/`

I think something went wrong when I deployed the server. How do I deploy it correctly?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` method to remove that from your url :

```js
var url = 'url/dist/img'

var updatedUrl = url.replace('/dist','')

// GET(updatedURL, ...
console.log(updatedUrl)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in Vue it automatically concatenates strings

Comment: can you should your get request ?

Comment: Yeah, but there's one more /dist/ ,So the image is not successful